# Define Federated Object on DB2

Tags: database, db2, federated

I'm currently learning the basics of DB2 in school.
Right now we are working on Federated Data Sources.

I've been trying to solve this one exercise, but I'm stuck:

> In database DB001, table SH1.TB001 is to be included as a Federated Data Source.
> The Federated Object should have the name NTAB (the nickname) and be defined in schema SH1.

I'm searching a solution on the IBM Knowledge Center, but I couldn't find anything.

I have to work essentially directly on my CentOS server, with the terminal. The only "external" programm I can use is DBeaver.

Since I have no experience with this, any type of help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Look at the `CREATE NICKNAME` statement description in the Knowledge Center.

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for your help.

I found a good example, but I'm still quite confused.

This is the example: Create a nickname for a view, DEPARTMENT, that is in a schema called HEDGES. This view is stored in a Db2 for z/OS data source called OS390A.

CREATE NICKNAME DEPT FOR OS390A.HEDGES.DEPARTMENT

I know the schema and the table, but I don't know if there's already a data source. Are there any way to find it out?

Comment: Look at the [SYSCAT.SERVERS catalog view](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002187.html) to get registered data sources. It would be useful to study architecture of [Federation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/doc/t0070493.html) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is two way to access remote data in DB2:

1.create a nickname, and use it as local table:

```
Create NICNAME SCHMx.NICKNAMEx for <remote server>.<remote schema>.<remote table>
```

then you can use SCHMx.NICKNAMEx as a local table:

```
select count(*) from SCHMx.NICKNAMEx
```

2.Use Federated three-part names:

```
select count(*) from <remote server>.<remote schema>.<remote table>
```

you can find the documentation her: https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/iiyfq3pnintro.html